# How to disable randomization on stained glass filter in photoshop for videos?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, video

When I apply the stained glass filter to a video in photoshop and render it out it generates a new pattern of cells each frame which leads to flickering.

What I want is an effect that has flat shaded cells but the pattern remains the same for the entire video. 
Is that possible with the build-in tools? If not, how can I edit the code for the stained glass filter to always use the same pattern?

Comment: You'd need to manually make that once in a pattern you like and have it as an overlay but it won't be dynamic and change to each scene. This seems better suited to After Effects than Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

Go into filter gallery and add a stained glass filter, after that add another one and hide the first. That will make the pattern stay the same throughout the whole video.

Comment: The workaround part has vanished into thin air!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a workaround. There's a software category Photo Mosaic Software which probably includes something for you, too.  I haven't one, I have only seen demonstrations and watched manuals.

Check at least AndreaMosaic http://www.andreaplanet.com/andreamosaic/

It has several versions: free and paid, for photos and videos, Win, Mac, Linux.

It allows custom tiling patterns and without a doubt gives a possiblity to use the same pattern repeatedly. The tiles can be smaller photos (=the basic meaning of term photo mosaic) Having flat color tiles is a special case of this.